# handsontable how is it possible to change the scrollbar next to the table

Tags: scrollbar, handsontable

I need to change how the scrollbar is displayed in handsontable. Who knows how to do this?

```
function WalkontableScroll(instance) {
this.instance = instance;
this.wtScrollbarV = new WalkontableScrollbar(instance, 'vertical');
`enter code here`this.wtScrollbarH = new WalkontableScrollbar(instance, 'horizontal');
}
```

Comment: What is your question? what do you need help with? And how is this part of handsontable? Can you share more of your code?

Comment: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/arrows.html - I want do some like this with standart handsontable plugin http://handsontable.com/

Answer (score -1):

If you want scrollbars, just set container width, height and `overflow: scroll` in CSS.

```
$example1.handsontable({
  data: createBigData(),
  colWidths: [55, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80], //can also be a number or a function
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: true,
  minSpareRows: 1,
  stretchH: 'all',
  contextMenu: true,
  width: 100,
  height: 100
});
```

See [here](http://handsontable.com/demo/scroll.html) for more detail

Comment: No. I need some to get scrollbar with scroll buttons. Like heer http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/complete_examples.html